USB permission not automatically granted for filtered devices in Android manifest, ACTION_USB_PERMISSION not triggered
I'm developing an Android application that manages USB devices using an external library. The MainActivity instantiates this library, which handles USB device events (connect/disconnect) and permissions via a BroadcastReceiver. My goal is to automatically grant permission to devices specified in an XML filter file upon connection, without explicitly calling requestPermission.
Here's what I've set up:
In AndroidManifest.xml, I added a <intent-filter> for USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED and specified a device_filter.xml file to match specific devices:
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

<application ... >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                   android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>

My device_filter.xml contains vendor and product IDs for devices I want to handle:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="2965" product-id="6032" />
    <usb-device vendor-id="10374" product-id="32807" />
</resources>

In my UsbCdc class, which handles the USB logic, I initialize a BroadcastReceiver that listens for ACTION_USB_PERMISSION and USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED:
public UsbCdc(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mUsbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,
            new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    ContextCompat.registerReceiver(mContext, mUsbReceiver, filter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
}

When I connect devices that match device_filter.xml, hasPermission(device) still returns false. In mUsbReceiver, if a device lacks permissions, I call mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent). However, ACTION_USB_PERMISSION is not triggered afterward, even though I have manually granted permissions.
Is automatic permission granting for devices in device_filter.xml dependent on the Android version or specific device settings? Why might ACTION_USB_PERMISSION not be triggered after calling requestPermission in the BroadcastReceiver?
